# How To prevent To Add specific duplicate Word in List Box

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

i wounder if i Can To prevent To Add specific duplicate Word, 
i not talking about item

i talk to prevent to add specific word if it already Exist in listbox, So if founded that specific word, will not add it again, but in same time can change it for another value to "Doby"

For Example:

i have (1 Textbox, 1 Listbox, 1 Button)

So i typed "Dianna" in textbox, if it found in listbox, then it will prevent to add duplicate "Dianna" name in listbox, but in same time will Change ,That only "Dianna" word founded from listbox To "Doby"

is that possible, i already created code, to check if it already founded or not, but problem
( i cant prevent To Add that specific duplicate Word in same ListBox, And can't To change that specific word "dianna" to "Doby")

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim One As String = Me.TextBox1.Text
    Dim Two As ListBox = Me.ListBox1
    ' Two.SelectedIndex = -1
    TextBox1.Text = "Doby"
    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    If One.Length > 0 Then
        For Check As Integer = 0 To Two.Items.Count - 1
            If Two.Items(Check).ToString.Contains(One) Then
                ' Two.SelectedIndices.Add(Check)
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

[Forum Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62fBB.png)

Sorry My english so bad, Thanks For help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a little way off from being correct,
If you look at the sample below,
it is written a little long-winded but that is written with the aim of trying to help you follow what's happening and then you can shorten the code accordingly to your preferred coding style.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    '
    Dim TextItem As Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem

    '-> load the inital list items
    TextItem = New Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Gen-Adams", "Gen-Adams")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextItem)
    TextItem = New Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Michael-Dianna", "Michael-Dianna")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextItem)
    TextItem = New Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("Gessy-Kristen", "Gessy-Kristen")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextItem)
    '-> Init textboxes
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = "Doby"

End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    '
    Dim Counta As Integer
    Dim Matched As Boolean
    Dim TmpListItem As Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem
    '
    '-> validate "look for" text
    If Trim(TextBox1.Text) <> "" Then
        '-> validate "replace with" text
        If Trim(TextBox2.Text) <> "" Then
            '-> if listbox contains items
            If ListBox1.Items.Count > 0 Then
                Matched = False
                For Counta = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
                    'ListBox1.SetSelected(Counta, True)
                    TmpListItem = ListBox1.Items(Counta)
                    '-> try to search for text
                    If InStr(TmpListItem.Text, TextBox1.Text) > 0 Then
                        '-> search text DOES exist in listitem text
                        TmpListItem.Text = Replace(TmpListItem.Text, TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)
                        ListBox1.Items(Counta) = TmpListItem
                        ListBox1.Refresh()
                        Matched = True
                    Else
                        'word not found in this list-item
                    End If
                Next
                If Not Matched Then
                    '-> No matches were found - add search word to list
                    TmpListItem = New Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(TextBox1.Text)
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(TmpListItem)
                End If
            Else
                'The listbox is empty - do something here
                TmpListItem = New Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(TextBox1.Text)
                ListBox1.Items.Add(TmpListItem)
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("No replacement word entered!")
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("No search word entered!")
    End If
    '-> Clear search/replacement textboxes
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    '
End Sub
```